# How do I do graph-oriented programming?

Tags: java, php, graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: how to represent graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737627/java-how-to-represent-graphs)

I heard about directed graphs, undirected graphs, acrylic graphs, etc. How would I make them in Java or PHP? Are they just arrays? I tried searching it up on Google but all of the results were too complex for me to understand.

Comment: You can see the basics of Graphs (in Java)  http://krishnalearnings.blogspot.in/2015/11/basics-of-graph-in-computer-science.html  and then you would need to traverse the Graph, we usually follow 2 methods DFS and BFS http://krishnalearnings.blogspot.in/2015/11/understanding-depth-first-search-dfs.html and http://krishnalearnings.blogspot.in/2015/11/breadth-first-search-in-java-using.html see these and you would be able to start Graph based programming. These are simple implementations.