# Representing a Graph in Java

Tags: java, graph, graph-algorithm, maze, adjacency-list

I am developing a maze system but not graphically maze system. The maze is actually referred as undirected graph I think because they don't direct to each other. The maze looks like this from a text file:

```
11 3
2 3
0 3
1 4
5 4
5 7
6 7
7 8
8 9
9 10
0 5
```

I don't know if I did was right to represent this in graph. If you check my code, it seems to be right, isn't it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Arc {
    public int nodeNo;
    public Arc next;

    public Arc(int nodeNo, Arc next) {
        this.nodeNo = nodeNo;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "" + nodeNo;
    }
}

class Node {
    int index;
    Arc adjList;

    Node(int index, Arc adjList) {
        this.index = index;
        this.adjList = adjList;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "" + index;
    }

}

public class Maze {

    Node[] stack;
    private Scanner scan;
    private static Scanner scan2;

    public Maze(String mazeFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
        scan = new Scanner(new File(mazeFile));

        stack = new Node[12];

        for (int n = 0; n < stack.length; n++) {
            stack[n] = new Node(n, null);
        }

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            int v1 = indexForNode(scan.next());
            int v2 = indexForNode(scan.next());

            stack[v1].adjList = new Arc(v2, stack[v1].adjList);
            stack[v2].adjList = new Arc(v1, stack[v2].adjList);
        }

    }

    int indexForNode(String index) {
        for (int n = 0; n < stack.length; n++) {
            if (stack[n].index == Integer.parseInt(index)) {
                return n;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }       

    public void print(){
        System.out.println();
        for(int n = 0; n < stack.length; n++){
            System.out.print(stack[n]);
            for(Arc arc = stack[n].adjList; arc != null; arc = arc.next){
                System.out.print(" --> " + stack[arc.nodeNo].index);
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter maze file name: ");
        String file = scan2.nextLine();
        Maze maze = new Maze(file);
        maze.print();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In general, I would say no: this is not a good approach.**  A basic graph, where the edges don't have weights, is implemented as a series of nodes with a `Many ↔ Many` relationship.

So basically your Node would look like this:

```
public class Node {
    private List<Node> out; 
}
```

**See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737627/java-how-to-represent-graphs?rq=1) for more information.**

Comment: So it does not have any other attributes of Node, is that what you mean? Instead of List, Can I use array instead? If not, why?

Comment: You can certainly add attributes to the node.  You also could use an array, but no serious programmer would use an array here.  Using a list means the list maintains the size for you and makes it easy to iterate through.

Comment: Oh I see... I can understand now. Thanks.. I've learned something new. You can tell already that I have bad programming logic apologise for that. :)